# Switch from Ubuntu to Kubuntu -- 14.04

Tags: apt, 14.04, kubuntu, convert

What is the command to remove all Ubuntu apps from a Kubuntu desktop, and vice versa, in Ubuntu 14.04? I want to keep the new Unity Locker, but remove everything else :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, just `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` is enough to switch to KDE/Kubuntu.

After that one could try `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up left-over packages from Ubuntu's default desktop.

Comment: I believe that the OPs question was how to remove the alternate desktop, rather than how to install a new one.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thank you for the feedback. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to install kubuntu is:

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Apart from that to Switch Between The New Unity Lockscreen And LightDM In Ubuntu 14.04

Firstly install CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM):

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Then open CompizConfig Settings Manager, click on Ubuntu Unity Plugin and on the General tab, under "Lockscreen", you can select to use Unity, LightDM or no lockscreen:

That's it - there's no need to restart the system or log out, the settings should be applied instantly.

Comment: This may be misleading: ubuntu-desktop is a metapackage; essentially it won't really remove anything.

Comment: Then how do I get rid of the *ubuntu-desktop and replace it with other *ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: As @William mentioned, this is wrong

Comment: Try http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/index (see the "Playing Around") section on the left.